# How to resolve the acceleration vector into tangential and normal vector?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vectors

$20)$ A particle moves so that its position vector at time $t$ is $r = t^2i + tj$.

d) resolve the acceleration vector at $t = 1$ into tangential and normal component.

Now the acceleration vector is just $a = 2i$ right? How can I "induce" $t$ into the acceleration expression?

Comment: Can you find the unit tangent vector to r(t) from your equation for r(t)?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Hi Thanks for commenting, no I am not sure

Comment: The accelaration is independent of $t$, and there is no need to do anything about that. But the concepts of "tangential" and "normal" do depent on that tangent to the curve, which does depend on $t$. Hence even if $a$ does not depend on $t$, its tangential and normal components do.